# Two employees sharing the same profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-team

See in the bottom of the [Our Team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) page:

> [image]

And:

> [image]

Natalie does have a [Stack Exchange account](https://stackexchange.com/users/2107728/natalie-eisen) so the link is correct, however it looks like Valentina Perez doesn't have any account and for some reason it's linking to the previous employee.

Worth to mention that in the [Welcome Message](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/max-oded-wendy-val-shefali-and-mike-welcome-to-the-family/) neither of them is linked to a profile.

Comment: What is even stranger is that they have never been seen together....

Comment: Strange even she has not notice this mistake.

Comment: @Lucifer as Office Manager she has very limited time to browse the internet, the staff is always hungry! ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You have a special interest in checking women's profiles  ;) (just kidding)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oh, Val does have an [account](https://stackexchange.com/users/2423881/val-perez) – including an excellent avatar no less:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And now it's also correctly linked on the team page.

Comment: Nice, I was looking for profile with the full name, didn't think to search for just "Val". Why no diamond though to the pretty lady? ;)

Comment: Not all employees get diamonds, only those who need them. E.g. a sales person or (as in this case) an office manager hardly needs moderator powers.

Comment: @balpha: I fail to see the downside... "Buy our stuff!" - "No, I don't want to!" - "Buy our stuff or I'll ban your employees from SO!" - "...they would go on strike! Well, where do I sign?"

Comment: @Won't nice pics! ;)

Comment: @Won't - Don't forget: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sgeRl.png